# How to parse JSON object array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Want to parse JSON object array using PHP, but I don't know how to do it as I am new to PHP.

Here is my JSON (Structure can't be altered since the JSON is constructed by other system):

```
[
{
"animalName":"Fox",
"animalId":"1"
},
{
"animalName":"Elephant",
"animalId":"2"
},
{
"animalName":"Monkey",
"animalId":"3"
},
{
"animalName":"Donkey",
"animalId":"4"
}
]
```

I used json_decode function to decode it but I dont know how to read values inside the json.

For ex: How would I get the value Monkey by parsing the JSON.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5):

This will do it

```
$data = json_decode($json);

$data[0]->animalName; // "Fox"
```

Per a useful comment

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($data);
```

Comment: You can also do `print_r("<pre>" . $data . "</pre>", true);` to make it nicely formatted while showing the whole thing :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

When I have the JSON as hardcoded one, I am able to decode it, But when I am trying to decode JSON that I am getting via HTTP post, it is not working.

PHP code is here:

<?php
$json = $_POST["animaljson"];
//$json = '[{"animalName":"Fox","animalId":"1"},{"animalName":"Fox","animalId":"1"}]';
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data[0]->animalName;
?>

Please suggest if I miss something here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all in a loop you can do as

```
$str='[
{
"animalName":"Fox",
"animalId":"1"
},
{
"animalName":"Elephant",
"animalId":"2"
},
{
"animalName":"Monkey",
"animalId":"3"
},
{
"animalName":"Donkey",
"animalId":"4"
}
]';

$data = json_decode($str,true);

foreach($data as $k=>$v){
 echo "Animal Name :".$v["animalName"]."<br />";
  echo "Animal ID :".$v["animalId"]."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

When I have the JSON as hardcoded one, I am able to decode it, But when I am trying to decode JSON that I am getting via HTTP post, it is not working.

PHP code is here:

<?php
$json = $_POST["animaljson"];
//$json = '[{"animalName":"Fox","animalId":"1"},{"animalName":"Fox","animalId":"1"}]';
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data[0]->animalName;
?>

Please suggest if I miss something here.

Comment: can u try `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');` instead of POST and then decode that.